# Does Phonegap supports native Android menu?

Tags: android, cordova

Is there a workaround or a phonegap plugin using which its possible to create native contextual menu in Android? I'm not looking to inject/show HTML on menu press event, rather I'm looking for a native route to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add a native menu to the class that extends DroidGap, just as you would any other activity, as DroidGap itself is just a child class of Activity.

Comment: and what would that look like?

Comment: It looks exactly like adding a menu to any other Activity. The main DroidGap Activity is a wrapper for a WebView and all the html/js/native-hooks that PhoneGap provides. The home activity that extends DroidGap can manage native menus just like any other Android Activity: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: just remember that you will have to redo this for every other mobile platform... so this kind of defeats the phonegap paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

phonegap only loads an html page. then u can create anything on that html page using javascript and access the native things like camera, gallery tc using phonegap.
You can create a page in native code and then load an html page on clicking on something using phonegap.
But wont that be defeating the purpose of phonegap?
There are loads of JS libraries that give the native look and feel