# Phonegap: How to make javascript calls from a native Android menu

Tags: javascript, android, menu, cordova

I am developing an android app by using phonegap however I would like to know how to make javascript calls (they are in my external js file) in the native android menu. Lastly would i be able to use the history api in this method?

Comment: no solutions on this I am sure it has been attempted before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Does Phonegap supports native Android menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701825/does-phonegap-supports-native-android-menu)

 also check out the phonegap plugins, u can learn how to attach js hooks then...